# Retransmitting failed messages with log4j socket appender

Tags: log4j

I'm sending log messages with log4j 2 socket appender to a log server. If the remote server shuts down messages get lost. I want to retransmit them when the connection re establishes.
I could probably do it by catching the socket exception and saving the message to a temporary queue. Can it be done using only log4j configuration? Maybe using a failover appender or some such?

Edit:
Any ideas? Maybe with async appender. It already has a queue.

Answer (score 1):

That's quite difficult. Because it should be some kind of reliable protocol. E.g. the fact that something was sent by socket doesn't mean it was received and written to a disk/etc. Have a look at `JMSAppender` for example.

For a simple fail-over you could just use two appenders and two remote servers, just don't reboot them both at the same time.

However, a logger is not something you should care too much about reliability. If you have a business requirement for it, you should implement it somehow differently using appropriate tools.

Comment: I'm not looking for guaranteed delivery here. More like best effort.

Comment: @GaryH Updated answer with a simple fail-over approach. I believe the temporary queue is not good idea.